# Existence of $\varepsilon$-optimal Borel measurable policies in stochastic control

Tags: measure-theory, optimization, optimal-control

I am reading the book *"Stochastic Optimal Control: The Discrete Time Case", by Bertsekas and Shreve* (hereafter called "**the Book**"), and I recently observed that a statement made in page 10 of the book (Introduction) seems that can be stated somewhat more generally.

The statement under question is described in the following:

Let $\mathscr{B}_\mathbb{R}$, $\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebras on $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^2$, and consider a Borel measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, such that

\begin{equation}
\inf_{u\in\mathbb{R}}g\left(x,u\right)>-\infty,\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}

Consider now the set of all *Borel measurable functions (policies)* from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and denote it by $\cal{P}$.

**I claim** that, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a Borel measurable policy $\mu_\varepsilon\in\cal{P}$, such that

\begin{equation}
g\left(x, \mu_\varepsilon \left(x \right) \right) \le\inf_{u\in\mathbb{R}}g\left(x,u\right) + \varepsilon,\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}

In the Book, on the other hand, it is claimed that the inequality above holds only almost everywhere, with respect to some given probability measure on $\mathscr{B}_\mathbb{R}$.

The proof of **my claim** follows.

---

First, for any measurable policy $\mu\in\cal{P}$, it holds that

\begin{equation}
g\left(x,\mu \left( x \right) \right) \ge 
\inf_{\mu\in\cal{P}}g\left(x, \mu \left( x \right) \right) \ge
\inf_{u\in\mathbb{R}}g\left(x,u\right)>-\infty,\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}

Fix an $\varepsilon>0$. Then, there exists a Borel measurable policy $\mu_\varepsilon\in\cal{P}$, such that

\begin{equation}
g\left(x, \mu_\varepsilon \left(x \right) \right) \le
\inf_{\mu\in\cal{P}}g\left(x, \mu \left( x \right) \right) + \varepsilon,\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}

Note that such a policy may be always found, since otherwise we would be led to a contradiction: If such a  policy does not exist, then it would be true that

\begin{equation}
g\left(x, \mu \left(x \right) \right) >
\inf_{\mu\in\cal{P}}g\left(x, \mu \left( x \right) \right) + \varepsilon,\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R},
\end{equation}

for all $\mu\in\cal{P}$, contradicting the fact that $\inf_{\mu\in\cal{P}}g\left(x, \mu \left( x \right) \right)$ is the infimum over $\mu\in\cal{P}$.

Now, since $\cal{P}$ is the class of all Borel measurable functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself, the set containing all constant policies, defined as

\begin{equation}
\mu_u \left( x \right) \triangleq u,\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R},
\quad\text{for some } u\in\mathbb{R},
\end{equation}

will be a *subset* of $\cal{P}$, and, therefore,

\begin{equation}
\inf_{\mu\in\cal{P}}g\left(x, \mu \left( x \right) \right) \le
g\left(x, \mu_u \left( x \right) \right) =  g\left(x, u \right)
\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad\text{and}\quad \forall u\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}

In particular, taking infima on both sides, it will also be true that

\begin{equation}
\inf_{\mu\in\cal{P}}g\left(x, \mu \left( x \right) \right) \le
\inf_{u\in\mathbb{R}}g\left(x, u \right)
\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}

This last inequality implies that there exists $\mu_\varepsilon\in\cal{P}$, such that

\begin{equation}
g\left(x, \mu_\varepsilon \left(x \right) \right) \le\inf_{u\in\mathbb{R}}g\left(x,u\right) + \varepsilon,\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}

for any arbitrary chosen $\varepsilon>0$, which seems to prove **my claim**.

---

Have I done anything wrong in the above derivations?
Why is claimed in the Book that this result holds only almost everywhere in $x$?

Thanks!

Comment: *Note that such a policy may be always found, since otherwise we would be led to a contradiction.* Can you elaborate here? Second point where you may get it wrong is that for constant policies you can't take infimum over all $x$: the original infimum allows $u$ to depend on $x$ (in a non-measurable way in general), whereas the infimum over constant policies does not.

Comment: IIya, first, thanks. I have updated my post to include the detail you asked for.
Regarding you second comment, I am not taking an infimum over all $x$, but over all $u$. Can you please explain more?

Comment: Sure, thanks. First of all, *Then, there exists a Borel measurable policy*: the definition of the infimum only implies that for every *given* $x$ there exists an $\varepsilon$, which may of course depend on $x$ in general - but there's no guarantee such an $\varepsilon > 0$ can be applied uniformly in $x$. Don't forget that whenever you try to have contradiction, and negate some statement, then $\forall x$ becomes $\exists x$.